# Contar número de comparações e troca em um algoritmo de ordenação por seleção em python

Tags: python, algoritmo, classificação

Preciso contabilizar o número de comparações e troca no seguinte algoritmo de ordenação por seleção:

```
def selecao(lista):
    c1 = c2 = 0
    for i in range(0, (len(lista)-1)):
        mini = i
        c1 += 1
        for j in range(i+1, len(lista)):
            c1 +=1
            if lista[j] < lista[mini]:
               c1 += 1
               c2 += 1
               mini = j

    lista[mini], lista[i] = lista[i],lista[mini]

    return c1, c2
```

Dessa forma estou contabilizando quantas vezes o algoritmo entra em um laço de repetição, não sei assim é o modo apropriado de contar quantas comparações. Além disso, preciso que a função retorne o número de trocas realizadas pela linha:

```
lista[mini], lista[i] = lista[i],lista[mini]
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda, sou novato em python

Comment: Número de comparações: `c2`; Número de trocas realizadas: `c1`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para o número de comparações você pode usar o `c2`, mas não use o `c1` para o número de trocas porquê há momentos que ele ira contabilizar duas vezes, para isso use uma variável fora da condição, algo como

```
c1 += 1
Ntrocas += 1
if lista[j] < lista[mini]:...
```